# Google map working in html but not in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, api, pyqt5

I'm trying to embed a Google Maps web view inside a PyQt5 Window. But the map is rendered correctly in plain HTML but throws an error while rendering in Python. I tried running the code separately in plain HTML and inside a PyQt5 Web view.

My HTML code is following

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Google Maps - gmplot</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&key=MY_KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.980700, 80.188200)
        });

        var marker_icon_FF0000 = {
            url: "data:image/png;base64,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",
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(10, 11)
        };

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(12.980700, 80.188200),
            icon: marker_icon_FF0000,
            map: map
        });

    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine but when I try to run this code inside a PyQt5 WebView Widget like following

```
# app.py
import gmplot
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class Browser(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        html = """
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Google Maps - gmplot</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&key=MY_KEY"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                    zoom: 18,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.980700, 80.188200)
                });

                var marker_icon_FF0000 = {
                    url: "data:image/png;base64,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",
                    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(10, 11)
                };

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(12.980700, 80.188200),
                    icon: marker_icon_FF0000,
                    map: map
                });

            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
        </body>
        </html>

        """

        here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).replace('\\', '/')
        base_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(here), 'dummy').replace('\\', '/')
        self.url = QtCore.QUrl('file:///' + 'map.html')
        self.page().setHtml(html, baseUrl=self.url)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):
        self.browser = Browser()
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.load_finished)

    def init_layout(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def load_finished(self, status):
        self.msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        self.msg.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information)
        self.msg.setWindowTitle('Load Status')
        self.msg.setText(f"It is {str(status)} that the page loaded.")
        self.msg.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get this error on the console saying `"js: You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started"`

I mean why is it working in plain HTML file and not in the web view.

Screenshots -

(Running inside PyQT Widget)

[image]

(Running inside Browser as HTML)

[image]

Comment: Is the map visible? That is, you can see the map but the problem is that this log appears, am I correct?

Comment: Yes the map is visible but with an overlay saying "For development purposes only"(running inside PyQT Widget), which doesn't happen when I open it in a browser(running HTML file).

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you point to?

Comment: Edited the question for you

Comment: How long ago did you get the API Key? Currently google requires you to have a payment account and initially gives you a bonus, have you done that? There are many tutorials in this regard so I recommend you review them. I recommend you go to the links shown in the log

Comment: No the account does not have billing setup but my doubt was why is it fine running in the browser. I mean what is wrong displaying it in the web view.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all - do make sure that you billing account at google maps is enabled and this should solve your problem :)

besides that I must say that I have also played with google maps a little and it is a riddle for me. Sometimes it works without user's credential at all and sometimes not. No idea why the difference.

But really enabling paying is safe, unless you have thousands of API calls you won't get billed. Just do it and move forward.

This is what I would do.

Comment: Why does it work inside the browser when I open the HTML file and not in the PyQt Webview then

Comment: Check the console with you HTML file, I think it throws an error that PyQT has a problem with

Comment: No the console does not display any errors either in HTML or PyQT except the one where it says billing should be enabled in case of PyQT but works fine when opened in a browser

Comment: but have you make sure that you billing account at google maps is enabled, and you still has the prblem or that you haven't done it, but you didn't had the problem with the HTML and then didn't bother to enable your billing accunt?

Comment: No billing is not setup in my account. My doubt is if it doesn't run without billing enabled then how is it loading in the browser when I run the HTML file.